# Enable IPV6FORWARDING on KVM host on CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, kvm-virtualization, ipv6

I have here a KVM host on which is running CentOS 7. If my `/etc/sysconfig/network` looks like

```
HOSTNAME=myname
NETWORKING_IPV6=yes
NETWORKING=yes
```

IPv6 was enabled and I get a global IPv6 address:

```
# ifconfig
br0-enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 2a02:aaa:bbbb:cccc:82ee:73ff:fe9d:5909  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 fe80::82ee:73ff:fe9d:5909  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 80:ee:73:9d:59:09  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 5798  bytes 614164 (599.7 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 1842  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 3037  bytes 3130986 (2.9 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::82ee:73ff:fe9d:5909  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 80:ee:73:9d:59:09  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 7595  bytes 915426 (893.9 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 5790  bytes 3458964 (3.2 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Lokale Schleife)
    RX packets 2874  bytes 2846558 (2.7 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 2874  bytes 2846558 (2.7 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.169.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.169.1.255
    ether 52:54:00:88:24:d4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe08:24af  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether fe:54:00:08:24:af  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 733  bytes 206871 (202.0 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 4312  bytes 400237 (390.8 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

But if I enable IPV6FORWARDING in `/etc/sysconfig/network`:

```
HOSTNAME=myname
NETWORKING_IPV6=yes
NETWORKING=yes
IPV6FORWARDING=yes
```

I get no global IPv6 address:

```
# ifconfig
br0-enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::82ee:73ff:fe9d:5909  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 80:ee:73:9d:59:09  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 8727  bytes 995519 (972.1 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 2446  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 4970  bytes 6890188 (6.5 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::82ee:73ff:fe9d:5909  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 80:ee:73:9d:59:09  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 11014  bytes 1383620 (1.3 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 10205  bytes 7423351 (7.0 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Lokale Schleife)
    RX packets 6159  bytes 6792034 (6.4 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 6159  bytes 6792034 (6.4 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.169.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.169.1.255
    ether 52:54:00:88:24:d4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe08:24af  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether fe:54:00:08:24:af  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 885  bytes 262087 (255.9 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 5626  bytes 512476 (500.4 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Content of the '/etc/sysctl.conf' is currently (already included the 'net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra' configuration of the answer of "A.B"):

```
# System default settings live in /usr/lib/sysctl.d/00-system.conf.
# To override those settings, enter new settings here, or in an /etc/sysctl.d/<name>.conf file
#
# For more information, see sysctl.conf(5) and sysctl.d(5).

#
# openvpn routing
#
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra=2
```

On other CentOS 7 machines on which no KVM host is installed it works. Anybody knows why?

**EDIT 19.12.09**

Adding content of '/etc/sysctl.conf' and adding full output of 'ifconfig'

Answer (score 0):

Here's a wild guess, considering you didn't provide much information (including the Host OS distribution):

Your system has probably this default sysctl setting:

```
# sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 1
```

Here's the [description](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?h=v4.19#n1508):

> ```
> accept_ra - INTEGER
>   Accept Router Advertisements; autoconfigure using them.
>
>   It also determines whether or not to transmit Router
>   Solicitations. If and only if the functional setting is to
>   accept Router Advertisements, Router Solicitations will be
>   transmitted.
>
>   Possible values are:
>       0 Do not accept Router Advertisements.
>       1 Accept Router Advertisements if forwarding is disabled.
>       2 Overrule forwarding behaviour. Accept Router Advertisements
>         even if forwarding is enabled.
>
>   Functional default: enabled if local forwarding is disabled.
>               disabled if local forwarding is enabled.
> ```

So when your host is not a router it's autoconfigured by the IPv6 router sending RAs (including in response to RSs from your host) on the network. When it becomes a router itself, by default it won't listen to those RAs.

Try this:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.br0-enp3s0.accept_ra=2
```

Note that since you're using the bridge's implicit self port to do routing, you can't distinguish where those RAs will come from: you could receive a RA from an untrusted VM: that's your call. You should also check if you need RAs on other interfaces.

All this could possibly not apply if for example you're configured with DHCPv6.

Comment: Thanks, but adding 'net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra=2' don't works. If I enable 'IPV6FORWARDING' I will don't have a IPv6 address. What information do you need? I have also added the content of '/etc/sysctl.conf'. Also I have added full output of 'ifconfig'. What do you mean with "Host OS distribution"? The host OS is CentOS 7 (like I have it described).

Comment: This was a wild guess, and it appears that wasn't it sorry (and yes I didn't read clearly that was the host being CentOS).

Comment: btw, just in case, did you try `sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.br0-enp3s0.accept_ra=2` as I wrote (br0-enp3s0, not all)?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. But without success. After enabling IPv6 (some weeks ago) on that machine I was wondering, why IPv6 was enabled on "br0-enp3s0" and not on "enp3s0" like I has it expected. But IPv6 works (of course without `IPV6FORWARDING`), I can connect via `ssh -6 ...` to that machine. However, may be I move the openvpn server to one of the KVM guests ...